# drag and drop is not work in react and typeScript (react-beautiful-dnd)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, drag-and-drop, react-beautiful-dnd

I am trying to create a todoList and pass tasks from Active Tasks to Completed Tasks
I used DragDropContext in the app class

I'm trying to create something like this https://taskify-typescript.netlify.app/
from https://github.com/piyush-eon/react-typescript-taskify/blob/master/src/components/SingleTodo.tsx

but the drag not work ..

**TodoList**

```
return (
<div className="container">
  <Droppable droppableId="TodosList">
    {(provided) => (
      <div className="todos"
       ref={provided.innerRef}
       {...provided.droppableProps}>

        <span className="todos_heading">Active Tasks</span>
        {todos?.map((todo,index) => (
          <SingleTodo
          index={index}
            todo={todo}
            key={todo.id}
            todos={todos}
            setTodos={setTodos}
          />
        ))}
        {provided.placeholder}
      </div>
    )}
  </Droppable>


  <Droppable droppableId="TodosRemove">
    {(provided) => (
      <div className="todos remove"
       ref={provided.innerRef}
        {...provided.droppableProps}>
            
       <span className="todos_heading">Completed Tasks</span>
    {completedTodos?.map((todo,index) => (
      <SingleTodo
      index={index}
        todo={todo}
        key={todo.id}
        todos={completedTodos}
        setTodos={setCompletedTodos}
      />
    ))}
    {provided.placeholder}
        </div>

        )}
        </Droppable>
  
</div>
```

);

**SingelTodo**

```
return (

<Draggable key={todo.id} draggableId={todo.id.toString()} index={index}>
  {(provided)=>
  (
    <form className="todos_single"
    onSubmit={(e) => handleEdit(e, todo.id)}
    ref={provided.innerRef} 
    {...provided.draggableProps} 
    {...provided.dragHandleProps}
    >
  {edit ? (
    <input
      ref={inputRef}
      value={editTodo}
      onChange={(e) => setEditTodo(e.target.value)}
      className="todos_single--text"
    />
  ) : todo.isDone ? (
    <s className="todos_single--text">{todo.todo}</s>
  ) : (
    <span className="todos_single--text">{todo.todo}</span>
  )}

  <div>
    <span
      className="icon"
      onClick={() => {
        if (!edit && !todo.isDone) setEdit(!edit);
      }}
    >
      <AiFillEdit />
    </span>
    <span className="icon" onClick={() => handleDelete(todo.id)}>
      <AiFillDelete />
    </span>
    <span className="icon" onClick={() => handleDone(todo.id)}>
      <MdDone />
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
  )}

</Draggable>

[enter image description here][3]
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the browser's console ?

Comment: Could you try creating a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we could inspect and debug live?